# How can i use JSTL variable in scriptlet?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, scriptlet

I have to access the JSTL variable which is calculated inside the iterator.
Excerpt of code:

```
<c:forEach var="resultBean" items="${resultList}" varStatus="status">
   card: ${resultBean.cardNum} 
</c:forEach>
```

i would like to access `${resultBean.cardNum}` in the scriptlet code. what i am doing right now is:

```
<c:forEach var="resultBean" items="${resultList}" varStatus="status">
   card: ${resultBean.cardNum} 
   <c:set var="currentCardNum">${resultBean.cardNum}</c:set>
   <%out.write( StringUtils.mask( (String)pageContext.getAttribute("currentCardNum") ) );%>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to skip 3rd line where i am setting the variable in pageContext. Is it possible to achieve the same result without setting it? Or is there other way round which i can use?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
<%
  ResultBean resultBean = (ResultBean) pageContext.getAttribute("resultBean");
  out.write( StringUtils.mask( resultBean.getCardNum() ) );
%>
```

BTW - you can add another method to resultBean - `getMaskedCardNum()`, and then just put in the page `${resultBean.maskedCardNum}` which is more readable.

Comment: He want to get rid of scriptlets, which is a Good Thing.

Comment: accepted: `you can add another method to resultBean - getMaskedCardNum()`

Comment: @BalusC - I agree, that's why I've put the second solution.

Answer (score 7):

I'd advise creating a custom JSTL function (check [this](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html) for example), so that you can omit the scriptlet.
So instead of the ugly

```
<%out.write( StringUtils.mask( (String)pageContext.getAttribute("currentCardNum") ) );%>
```

you will have something like:

```
<c:out value="${fnPrefix:maskString(currentCardNum)}" />
```